# Elasticsearch - Stop analyzer doesn't allow number

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm trying to build a search utility using elasticsearch 6.3.0 where any term can be searched within the database. I have applied Stop Analyzer to exclude some of the generic words. However, after having that analyzer system stopped giving me term with numbers as well.

Like if I search for news24 then it removes 24 and search only for "news" term in all records. Unsure why.

Below is the query I am using

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "explain": false,
   "stored_fields": [
      "_source"
   ],
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "news24",
               "analyzer": "stop",
               "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "keywords",
                  "url"
               ]
            }
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "( (doc['isSponsered'].value == 'y') ? 100 : 0 )"
               }
            },
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "doc['linksCount'].value"
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "sum",
         "boost_mode": "sum"
      }
   },
   "script_fields": {
      "custom_score": {
         "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "params._source.linksArray"
         }
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "pre_tags": [
         ""
      ],
      "post_tags": [
         "<\/span>"
      ],
      "fields": {
         "title": {
            "type": "plain"
         },
         "keywords": {
            "type": "plain"
         },
         "description": {
            "type": "plain"
         },
         "url": {
            "type": "plain"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had been facing the same issue, however unsure about describe it. Thank you for posting it in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `stop analyzer` is just an extension of [Simple Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) which makes use of [Lowercase Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenizer.html) which would simply break terms into tokens if it encounters character which is not a `letter` (of course also lowercasing all the terms).

So bascially if you have something like `news24` what it does it, breaks it into `news` as it encountered `2`.

This is the default behaviour of the `stop analyzer`. If you intend to make use of stop words and still want to keep numerics in picture, then you would be required to create a custom analyzer as shown below:

### Mapping:

```
POST sometestindex
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "my_english_analyzer":{  
               "type":"standard",
               "stopwords":"_english_"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What it does it it makes use of `Standard Analyzer` which internally uses [Standard Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) and also ignores stop words.

### Analysis Query To Test

```
POST sometestindex/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_english_analyzer",
  "text":     "the name of the channel is news24"
}
```

### Query Result

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "name",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "channel",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "news24",
      "start_offset": 27,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see in the above tokens, that `news24` is being preserved as token.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had been facing the same issue, thank you for the solution.